# Object could not be converted to string?

Tags: php

Why am I getting this error:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class Card could not be converted to
>   string in /f5/debate/public/Card.php on line 79

Here is the code:

```
public function insert()
{
    $mysql = new DB(debate);

    $this->initializeInsert();

    $query = "INSERT INTO cards
            VALUES('$this->$type','$this->$tag','$this->$author->$last','$this->$author->$first',
            '$this->$author->$qualifications','$this->$date->$year','$this->$date->$month',
            '$this->$date->$day','$this->$title', '$this->$source', '$this->$text')";
            $mysql->execute($query);
}
```

(Line 79 is the `$query` and the function is part of class `Card`)

All the declarations of `Card`:

```
public $type;

public $tag;
public $title;
public $source;
public $text;

public function __construct() {
    $this->date = new Date;
    $this->author = new Author;
}
```

---

After changing line 79 to this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO cards
    VALUES('$this->type','$this->tag','$this->author->last','$this->author->first',
    '$this-$author->qualifications','$this->date->year','$this->date->month','$this->date->day',
    '$this->title', '$this->source', '$this->text')";
```

I now get this error:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class Author could not be converted
>   to string in /f5/debate/public/Card.php on line 79

Comment: That's because of `$this-$author->qualifications`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Read about [**string parsing**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing), you have to enclose the variables with brackets `{}`:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO cards VALUES('$this->type','$this->tag','{$this->author->last}',"
```

Whenever you want to access multidimensional arrays or properties of a property in string, you have to enclose this access with `{}`. Otherwise PHP will only parse the variable up to the **first** `[i]` or `->property`.

So with `"$this->author->last"` instead of `"{$this->author->last}"`, PHP will only parse and evaluate `$this->author` which gives you the error as `author` is an object.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you need the $ sign when using arrow operator.

Answer (score 3):

you shouldn't put $ before property names when you access them:

```
public function insert() {
        $mysql = new DB(debate);
        $this->initializeInsert();
        $query = "INSERT INTO cards VALUES('$this->type','$this->tag','$this->author->last','$this->author->first','$this-$author->qualifications','$this->date->year','$this->date->month','$this->date->day','$this->title', '$this->source', '$this->text')";
        $mysql->execute($query);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to echo an object itself, not a string property of it. Check your code carefully.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO cards VALUES('$this->type','$this->tag' // etc
```

Answer (score 2):

I think one of the object doesn't have toString() method defined so it cannot be represented as string.