# Catchable fatal error: Object could not be converted to string

Tags: string, string-concatenation, php

In my Zend Framework application I'm getting this error:

`Catchable fatal error: Object of class User could not be converted to string in /home/trengine/domains/completeset.us/application/models/User.php on line 121`

Line 121 is the where clause in this mySql query:

```
$query = "SELECT first,
                         last,
                         email,
                         gender,
                         user_type,
                         country,
                         state,
                         province,
                         city,
                         DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%m/%d/%Y') AS birthday,
                         facebook_id
                         FROM users
                         WHERE user_id = '{$this->id}'";
```

Comment: `$this->id` might have accidently been converted to a `User` class, either way something your using there is actually an object where it should be a string, try using a PHP debugger or var_dumping `$this->id`

Comment: I think you're right Sammaye.

Comment: Related: [Object could not be converted to string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200899/object-could-not-be-converted-to-string)

Comment: @hakre this case was slightly different, my error was that id was being set to an object. In your linked question, it seems like they were trying to access object properties without brackets, so it was trying to convert $object to string and then treating the ->property as a string literal, at least as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this before you call the database:

```
var_dump($this->id);
```

This will show you what variable type you're dealing with. More than likely the id has been cast as an object somewhere along the lines.

Also, and my apologies in advance... but you should look into Zend DB Table Abstract and extend from it. You'll find it a lot easier down the road to perform any changes you need to make to your project.

Comment: Yeah, that's all it was, one page was setting the id to an object. And I'm already using Zend DB Adapter, I just find it easier to write most of my queries out.