# Object could not be converted to strings

Tags: jquery, session, laravel

My query causes: `Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string`. When I replace `$uname` with a hardcoded name `'Dennis'` in the model-query then the error disappears. I checked whether the session variable (`'username'`) was empty and causing the error but it is set. Thanks for any hint.

Controller:

```
$username = Session::get('username');
$data['users'] = Profile::GetUserData($username);
$users = Profile::GetUserData();

return View::make('profile_view', $data);
```

Model:

```
class Profile extends Eloquent{
    public function scopeGetUserData($uname){
        return DB::table('users')->where('user_name', '=', $uname)->first();
        //return DB::table('users')->where('user_name', '=', 'Dennis')->first();
    }
}
```

Comment: This code makes no sense whatsoever. That's not the code that threw that error. That's not the way you use scope functions. There are two calls to `GetUserData`, one correct, one with a missing parameter. What's going on here?

Comment: From the docs: "Scopes allow you to easily re-use query logic in your models." -> you should return query parts from scope functions, not actually query the DB. The error you posted has nothing to do with this code. You probably did not have that `->first()` there when that error was thrown. Or something else, no one can tell, there's all sorts of wrong stuff going on in your code. Try reading the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes

Comment: possible duplicate of [Object could not be converted to string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200899/object-could-not-be-converted-to-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Controller` following code is causing the problem because `getUserData()` expects an argument and you are calling that method without any argument like this:

```
$users = Profile::GetUserData();
```

The given code above is unnecessary because you are first calling the `getUserData()` method properly like this:

```
$data['users'] = Profile::GetUserData($username);
```

Then again calling that method improperly and this line has no use because you are passing the `$data` array to your `view`, so remove following line:

```
$users = Profile::GetUserData();
```

As a result your `Controller` may contain the code given below:

```
$username = Session::get('username');
$data['users'] = Profile::GetUserData($username)->first();
return View::make('profile_view', $data);
```

Also in your `scope method` you should use two parameters because first parameter will be injected by `Laravel` which will be the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` object and you should return this object instead of executing the query inside the method (using first) so you may chain other methods (if needed):

```
class Profile extends Eloquent{
    public function scopeGetUserData($query, $uname){
        return $query->where('user_name', $uname);
    }
}
```

But you may also call it like this:

```
public function scopeGetUserData($query, $uname){
    return $query->where('user_name', $uname)->first();
}
```

In this case your controller should be like this:

```
$username = Session::get('username');
$data['users'] = Profile::GetUserData($username);
return View::make('profile_view', $data);
```